# Data Modeling Relations vs DynamoDB

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, data-modeling

I am going to develop android mobile app and going to use AWS as backend. I am 
 planning to use DynamoDB as my backend database. I am new to NoSql.

In my app an user has many blogs. A blog has many posts and the post has many comments. Also user has many followers.

In this scenario, how can I create DynamoDB table for my requirement and what is the best practice?

Is following structure OK for my requirement?

```
{
    Blogname: 'Test Blog',
    Posts:[
        {
            Title: 'test',
            Description: 'Test.......',
            Comments: [
                {
                    Id: 11,
                    Comment: 'Test Comment',
                    CommentBy: 'Test User'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I suggest you stat by reading the DynamoDB Best Practices section of the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/best-practices.html and also, have a look at the canonical example given on several of the DynamoDB docs pages that shows how to model a Thread with Posts and Replies - not much different than your blog example.

Comment: Keep in mind that the idea is not to model your whole database as a single item! The idea is to try to keep items accessed together, together. In general, whereas a normalized relational database would have you decompose and structure data into discrete logical units, the no sql approach favors a denormalized structure where data is optimized for scaling and availability.

Comment: @MikeDinescu Thanks Mike, I will the document which you provide